# Wordpress plugin logo and banner is not displaying in my plugin page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

My Wordpress plugin page banner and logo is not displaying.

Currently, I published a plugin in WordPress. I followed this [guid](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/) and added the assets like [in this repo](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/assets). But the banner and logo are not showing don't know why. am new to WordPress.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pointing us to working examples does not help us at all. Post YOUR code here. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @disinfor its not about the code. it's only about the Wordpress plugin page banner and log, and how this should be configured in svn repo so that it will display in wordpress.org plugin page. this is my [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customerlabs-actionrecorder/) has an issue

Comment: Going to the plugin page, it looks fine - unless that's not your logo or banner. If it's not about code, then Stack Overflow is the wrong place to post your question.